# how to restart appication over cron.daily in Fedora 33

Tags: cron, sasl

I am using Fedora 33 and I have script, which I am trying to make working.
but without success ;-(
it is given to /etc/cron.daily

---

#!/bin/bash

RESTART="/bin/systemctl restart saslauthd"

---

it is very simple. I have known problem with SASLauth if You are using MariaDB.
it will crashed sometimes in one week, sometimes one month, but sometimes crash

I have added this script file to cron.daily and rights is 100755 - standard for all other scripts

where can be bug ?? all other scripts are working
is there some limitation for running services by cron ?? /I have added in "sudoers" also "cron ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL"